# Replace/Remove text in one column using value from another

Tags: sql-server, replace

I'm trying to remove text from a text column in sql server based on what is in a previous column in the same row.

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+---------------------
A123 | A123 This is A text
A444 | A444 This is B text
A333 | This is C text
```

I want to remove the `Col1` values from the `Col2`.

I have tried `select replace(COL2, Col1, '') from tbl` but that does not work.

Also sometimes `Col2` does not contain the text from `Col1` so I don't think I can do a `substring` based on length of `col1`.

Can I do this with an easy command?

**EDIT#1**: I added a 3 row to show how the `Col1` value sometimes isn't in `Col2`.
Also I'm just looking for a select and would like the below returned.

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+---------------------
A123 | This is A text
A444 | This is B text
A333 | This is C text
```

**EDIT#2**: My issue was solved via `LTRIM(RTRIM(col1))` before the replace and then it worked as expected.

Comment: Do you want to update your table or select the data in this manner? `Also sometimes Col2 does not contain the text from Col1 so I don't think I can do a substring based on length of col1.` Be more clear in the part.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what it is that isn't working for you?  If the string expression you are searching for isn't found, the function returns the original string unaltered. It is unclear why you think you need a to do a substring.

Comment: See edits please. Basically I just want to search col2 and if it finds the text that is in col1 remove it.

Comment: I have tried select replace(COL2, Col1, '') from tbl but that does not work. - in my opinion it should, please double check you didn't do a typo.

Comment: AH crap there was a space in col1 that wasn't in col2 so it wasn't finding it just had to add the trims. Sorry for bothering everyone.